# How can I endline in tabular environment?

Tags: line-breaking, indentation, line, emphasis, tabbing

How do you end line in a tabular environment so that it would stay in it's lane? I've made an improvisation but I would like it to be automated.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{NotoSerifHK-Regular}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\setmainfont{NotoSerif-Regular}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tabbing}
            \hspace{3em}\= {\large 三}\quad\= \emph{tam} \quad\= (nét trên chỉ Trời, nét dưới chỉ Đất, vậy Trời, Đất với Người \\* {\hspace{8.3em}cộng lại là ba}) \\[3pt]
            \> {\large 人} \> \emph{nhân} \> (vẽ hình người đi) \\[3pt]      
            \> {\large 日} \> \emph{nhật} \> (vẽ hình mặt trời tròn)
        \end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [`tabularx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) environment within a `quote` environment, perhaps with an adjusted `\arraystretch` definition if you like:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK HK}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
% I adjust \arraystretch to increase row spacing in tables a little.
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]

% Use a quote environment to provide left and right indent and some
% vertical spacing
\begin{quote}
  % insert a table which has a width of \linewidth
  % The column specification is {>{\large}l>{\em}lX}
  % The first column (l) is left alighned and \large is inserted at
  %     the beginning of each cell.
  % The second column (l) is left aligned and \em is inserted at the
  %     beginning of each cell
  % The third column (X) takes up the remaining horizontal space and 
  %     is justified
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\large}l>{\em}lX}
    三 & tam & (nét trên chỉ Trời, nét dưới chỉ Đất, vậy Trời, Đất với Người
    cộng lại là ba) \\
    人 & nhân & (vẽ hình người đi) \\
    日 & nhật & (vẽ hình mặt trời tròn) \\
  \end{tabularx}
\end{quote}

\lipsum[4]

\section*{Your \texttt{tabbing} environment for comparison}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{tabbing}
  \hspace{3em}\= {\large 三}\quad\= \emph{tam} \quad\= (nét trên chỉ Trời, nét dưới chỉ Đất, vậy Trời, Đất với Người \\* {\hspace{8.3em}cộng lại là ba}) \\[3pt]
  \> {\large 人} \> \emph{nhân} \> (vẽ hình người đi) \\[3pt]      
  \> {\large 日} \> \emph{nhật} \> (vẽ hình mặt trời tròn)
\end{tabbing}

\lipsum[4]


\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Can you add explanation in your code?

Comment: @AdrikIvanov, yeah I can. Also check out the [`tabularx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/tabularx.pdf) documentation.

Comment: @AdrikIvanov I added some comments.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to measure the texts and to use hanging indentation.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setCJKmainfont{IPAMincho}[ItalicFont=*]

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{hanilatn}{+b}
 {
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  \adrik_hanilatn:n { #1 }
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
 }{}

\seq_new:N \l__adrik_hanilatn_hani_seq
\seq_new:N \l__adrik_hanilatn_latn_seq
\dim_new:N \l__adrik_hanilatn_hani_dim
\dim_new:N \l__adrik_hanilatn_latn_dim

\cs_new_protected:Nn \adrik_hanilatn:n
 {
  \cs_set_eq:NN \word \__adrik_hanilatn_measure:nnn
  #1
  \cs_set_eq:NN \word \__adrik_hanilatn_typeset:nnn
  #1
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__adrik_hanilatn_measure:nnn
 {
  % measure
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l__adrik_hanilatn_hani_seq { #1 }
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l__adrik_hanilatn_latn_seq { #2 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__adrik_hanilatn_hani_seq
   {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { ##1 }
    \dim_set:Nn \l__adrik_hanilatn_hani_dim
     {
      \dim_max:nn { \l__adrik_hanilatn_hani_dim } { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
     }
   }  
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__adrik_hanilatn_latn_seq
   {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { ##1 }
    \dim_set:Nn \l__adrik_hanilatn_latn_dim
     {
      \dim_max:nn { \l__adrik_hanilatn_latn_dim } { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__adrik_hanilatn_typeset:nnn
 {
  \par\addvspace{0.5ex}
  \hangindent=\dim_eval:n { 5em + \l__adrik_hanilatn_hani_dim + \l__adrik_hanilatn_latn_dim }
  \hangafter=1~
  \hspace*{3em}
  \makebox[\l__adrik_hanilatn_hani_dim][c]{#1} % Han characters centered
  \hspace*{1em}
  \makebox[\l__adrik_hanilatn_latn_dim][l]{\itshape #2}
  \hspace*{1em}
  (#3)
  \par\addvspace{0.3ex}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% some text just to see the environment in context
Ngày Xuân (日) con én đưa thoi, Thiều quang chín chục đã ngoài sáu mươi.
Cỏ non xanh tận chân trời, Cành lê trắng điểm một vài bông hoa.
Thanh minh trong tiết tháng ba, Lễ là tảo mộ, hội là đạp Thanh.
Gần xa nô nức yến anh, Chị em (三人) sắm sửa bộ hành chơi xuân.

\begin{hanilatn}
\word{三}{tam}{nét trên chỉ Trời, nét dưới chỉ Đất, vậy Trời, Đất với Người cộng lại là ba}

\word{人}{nhân}{vẽ hình người đi}

\word{日}{nhật}{vẽ hình mặt trời tròn}
\end{hanilatn}

Ngày Xuân (日) con én đưa thoi, Thiều quang chín chục đã ngoài sáu mươi.
Cỏ non xanh tận chân trời, Cành lê trắng điểm một vài bông hoa.
Thanh minh trong tiết tháng ba, Lễ là tảo mộ, hội là đạp Thanh.
Gần xa nô nức yến anh, Chị em (三人) sắm sửa bộ hành chơi xuân.

\end{document}
```

The environment's content is processed twice. The first time two sequences are populated so we can measure the Han and the Latin parts (Hani is the ISO code for the Han and Latn for the Latin scripts).

After that we can reprocess the contents to typeset it, because we know the amount of hanging indentation needed.

**Production notes.** I use IPAMincho for Han because I don't have the Noto font you use. By the way, I find Noto Serif rather ugly. The surrounding text has been taken from another question of yours.

[image]